# How to give access to a list of UID in security rule of firebase realtime database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a database where the rules are simple, users can only write to their own individual child nodes.
But I also wanted the moderators that I listed in a child node/property to be able to access the users data.

How do I write the rules so that the listed admin uids (admin1, admin2, admin3) can access all user nodes?

[image]

The only solution I could come up with is only this, but it is not very convenient since its gonna be a long condition.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.uid === 'admin1' || auth.uid === 'admin2' || auth.uid === 'admin 3'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I thought I could reference the "uid" values under the admin node using the $ variable, but turns out that's not how the security rule works.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "admins":{
      "uid" : "$adminUIDs"
    }
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.uid.contains($adminUIDs)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I would approach this is to [utilize custom auth tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) that contain a custom claim for the user role.

That custom claim will then be [available for your Firebase RTDB rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) for more extensible authorization.

For example, after a user has successfully authenticated client-side, their auth token would be passed to the backend to generate a custom token:

```
const claims = {
  admin: true,
  someOtherClaim: "foobar"
};

getAuth()
  .createCustomToken(userId, claims)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

Afterwards in your RTDB rules, you can have much simpler logic to determine who has access to a particular record:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid || auth.token.admin === true || auth.token.someOtherClaim === 'foobar'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this would mean I need to run an authentication server on my computer right?

Comment: No, this is a built-in feature of Firebase Auth/IdP.  You would need to create a REST API endpoint that accepts the client-side token, generates a custom token and returns it.